# Jenkins Console Output is taking too long to print Failures after the tests are done running

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng, console-output

I have around 650 tests that runs in Jenkins everyday for regression. The tests are running fine but when the tests are done running Jenkins is taking too long(more than 2 hours for 50 tests) to print the Summary of the run.
I am not able to figure out what's causing it.

Post Steps is used in Job:
Executing a bash script under Execute shell for Extent Reports.

Few Post-build Actions are used in Job:
1.Publish TestNG results
2.Archive the artifacts
3.Publish HTML results
4.Editable Email Notification
5.Create Image Gallery

Any ideas on how to get around this problem?